# Javascript works locally and on firefox, but shows up blank in the inspector on other browsers

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, web-hosting

I have a website I'm designing for class, and the javascript/jquery works perfectly in a local directory and on firefox (for some reason), but doesn't on other browsers. I'm using Opera to test this site. When I use Inspect Element and look at the .js file, it shows up completely blank for some reason, even though its contents look fine from cPanel. There are no error messages to track down the issue either.

I transferred my files using ftp with FileZilla, and I'm using bluehost as a web hosting service. All my html files are in the public_html directory in cPanel, and my javascript file is in a subdirectory called _js. CSS files are loading fine, I've seen similar posts saying both js and css aren't working which isn't the case here.

This is my html. I also tried putting it before `</body>` without any more luck either. I've also tried using multiple srcs to Jquery libraries copied from other forum posts with similar questions, thinking maybe its a dependent library issue, but still nothing.

```
    <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="_js/javascript.js"></script>
</head>
```

My javascript is set up as so

```
$(document).ready(function () {
```

I've tried putting this DOMContentLoaded before, after, and inside the document ready function.

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);
```

I'm at my wits end. I can't find anywhere else with this specific problem. I saw somewhere about how Firefox checks over the files multiple times, but I don't really understand how, nor do I know how to make other browser do it. I also don't know why the inspector just thinks its a blank js file. I didn't think hosting Javascript would be so tedious.

Comment: Your browser (any modern browser) has a developer tool that will show you all attempted HTTP transactions based on your page content (JavaScript, CSS, images, fonts, etc).

Comment: You haven't provided us any HTML. At least a link to your site? What are we, mind readers?

Comment: I don't know how public I'm supposed to be with this kinda stuff, and it has some of my info on the site itself. but also now, it seems to be working??? I posted this after a class without checking but it works now?? I'm still new to this lol